# Geting a line break in reply message

Tags: codeigniter

I am very new to codigniter and trying to amend some code to insert line breaks in the quoted reply of a message text area. "\r\n" is just outputting as normal text. (it is part of an expressionengine module)

```
$tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single
('message', '---- Original Message ---- "\r\n" 
date: '. $original_date.' "\r\n" '.$original_body.' ---', $tagdata);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Dont use `"\r\n"` inside single qoutes, use it like this:

```
'---- Original Message ---- '."\r\n".' date: '
```

2.Try:

```
PHP_EOL
```

Its a [**predefined constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

```
$tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single
('message', '---- Original Message ---- '.PHP_EOL.' date: '. 
$original_date.PHP_EOL.$original_body.' ---', $tagdata);
```

Comment: Thank you that is perfect and solves my issue

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the "\r\n" inside the single quote

```
$tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single
('message', '---- Original Message ----'."\r\n".'
date: '. $original_date. "\r\n".$original_body.' ---', $tagdata);
```

Comment: This answer also works. Thank you. I had tried something similar but I think i got lost with the single and double quotes!